# access child scope property in another child in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

is it possible to access sibling properties in angular js?  I have a parent and two children

My parent is my parent div

children are:-

```
1. <li ng-repeat= "item in list"/>

2. and within ng-repeat i have a custom directive  <directive1></directive1>
```

depending upon the item types there can be different directives so i get my directives in item as a property

```
i.e. item.directive= "<div directive1> </directive>"
```

i compile the above html so that the code for directive1 is called!

now how do i access "item" in directive1's link function?

the link: function has scope and it has a property **$$childTail**  this shows me **item** which belongs to ng-repeat child scope! is it recommended to use it? or there is a work around? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in scope variables into directives and use them within the link function.

```
<div directive some-var="item"></div>
```

In your directive make sure you specify the scope.

```
scope: {
  someVar: '='
},
link: funciton (scope, element, attr) {
   // outputs the contents of 'item' from the parent scope.
   console.log(scope.someVar);
}
```